# Node.js RabbitMQ Worker Stops Responding After Some Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rabbitmq, queue

I had this worker which is consistently working and requests are comming to this worker but its not sending back the response after several minutes. Below is the code which is breaking. it take s token from the token_validation_requests and sends response to response queue.
I've noticed that after some time, this worker stops processing messages from the queue, even though RabbitMQ continues to send messages.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that my worker runs continuously without stopping?

````
export const startTokenValidationWorker = async () => {
  try {
    const { connection, channel } = await connectToRabbitMQ();

    const validationRequestQueue = "token_validation_requests";
    const replyQueue = "token_validation_responses";

    await channel.assertQueue(validationRequestQueue, { durable: true });
    await channel.assertQueue(replyQueue, { durable: true });

    console.log("Token validation worker started.");

    channel.consume(validationRequestQueue, async (msg) => {
      if (!msg) return;

      const { token } = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString());
      console.log({token})
      try {
        const decodedToken = await jwt.verify(
          token,
          process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY
        );

        const { userId, userRole } = decodedToken;

        const existingToken = await Token.findOne({
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
          status: true,
        });

        const validationResponse = {
          valid: !!existingToken,
          userId,
          userRole,
        };

        await channel.sendToQueue(
          msg.properties.replyTo,
          Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(validationResponse)),
          {
            correlationId: msg.properties.correlationId,
          }
        );

        channel.ack(msg);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
          const validationResponse = {
            error: "Token has expired",
          };
          await channel.sendToQueue(
            msg.properties.replyTo,
            Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(validationResponse)),
            {
              correlationId: msg.properties.correlationId,
            }
          );
          channel.ack(msg);
        } else if (error.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
          const validationResponse = {
            error: "Invalid token",
          };
          await channel.sendToQueue(
            msg.properties.replyTo,
            Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(validationResponse)),
            {
              correlationId: msg.properties.correlationId,
            }
          );
          channel.ack(msg);
        } else {
          channel.ack(msg);
        }
      }
    });

     // Add an infinite loop to keep the worker running
     while (true) {
      // Sleep for a while to avoid high CPU usage
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error starting token validation worker:", error);
  }
};```
````